# Unable to read query string in VB.NET web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have vb.net website and MVC 4 application. I am sending the query string from MVC application to VB application. The VB.Net application is hosted in IIS server.

Temporarily I am reading the query string on a label. The problem is that during first click the query-string doesn't get read. But during the second click on the same link, the query string gets printed on the label.

MVC code:

```
public JsonResult OpenK3oneWebLink(string strLinkName)
{
    string strWebLink = string.Empty;
    string linkName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (pclsConcurrency.UXControllerServiceClient.modifyUserStatus("T", pclsConcurrency.strUsersId) == true)
        {
            string[] arr = pclsConcurrency.m_strDBName.Split('_');
            string DBNameForUrl;
            if (arr.Length == 1)
            {
                DBNameForUrl = arr[0];
            }
            else
            {
                DBNameForUrl = arr[1];
            } 

eif (strLinkName == "daytoday")
            {
                strWebLink = "http://" + pclsConcurrency.m_strAppServer + "/K3OneWeb_" + DBNameForUrl + "/Environment/Login.aspx?intEntityId=" + pclsConcurrency.intEntityId + "&Users=" + pclsConcurrency.strUsersId;// +"192.168.0.163/K3OneWeb_aish1/Environment/Login.aspx?intEntityId=5&Users=SHG";
            }

else if (strLinkName == "Daily")
            {
                strWebLink = "http://" + pclsConcurrency.m_strAppServer + "/K3OneWeb_" + DBNameForUrl + "/Environment/Login.aspx?intEntityId=" + pclsConcurrency.intEntityId + "&Users=" + pclsConcurrency.strUsersId + "&linkname=Daily";
            }
```

and the vb.net code is

```
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString("intEntityId")
Label2.Text = Request.QueryString("Users")
Label3.Text = Request.QueryString("linkname")
```

it is written on page load event but, unable to retrieve it on the first click but get retrieved on the second click on the same link.The VB application is hosted on IIS server and MVC application is running locally.

TIA

Comment: "I am sending the query string from MVC application to VB application.". Are you? There's no code for it here. " during first click the query-string doesn't get read." First click of what, and where? There are no buttons or links in this code. You've described a problem with something which you then haven't shown. It's hard to be clear about what the problem is or understand the flow of the code.

Comment: The click is on weblink of mvc application, and query string must retrieved at vb.net application which is hosted on iis server.
I cant send the coding of the controller as it is too big to accommodate here

Comment: No-one said you have to post the whole thing, but more of the relevant parts would be useful. We can't see how you send the URL, but it looks like you don't bother to URLEncode the variables, so that could cause issues. Then on the VB.NET side, the 3 lines you've shown, on their own, look like they would show the data but since it's completely out of context we don't know if you've put the code in the right place etc. etc. You also haven't given any info about your debugging so far - did you trace the MVC code to be sure it actually sends the data?

Comment: And what does "unable to retrieve" mean? Are the values present on the querystring but just not being read by the VB code? Or are they never transmitted by MVC? You haven't been sufficiently clear about the problem or the code being used. Without more info, it's not possible to answer the question, which was the point I was making in my first comment.

Comment: the values present on the querystring are not being read by the VB code when we click the weblink for first time
Then on second time it works perfectly fine and querystring gets read by vb code.

Are there any other methods to send query string from mvc to vb code hosted in iis????

Comment: Sorry but that explanation just repeats your original wording,which wasn't precise enough. Can you please be more specific and answer my questions? And add the relevant code as suggested? I don't know if there are alternative ways to do it, because as I explained already, you aren't actually showing properly or fully the way that you're sending and receiving the data.